# I can not get my code to run due to a run time error when trying to assign the String userAns to input

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a simple quiz program.  The code on line 19 is giving me a run time error.  Could someone please advise why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class javaQuiz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String questionOne = "Who is the best band member of the beatles?";
    String questionOneAns = "John";

    String questionTwo = "what is 1 + 1?";
    int questionTwoAns = 2;

    String questionThree = "What continent is China a part of?";
    String questionThreeAns = "Asia";

    String questionFour = "Who is the Turing Test named after?";
    String questionFourAns = "Alan Turing";

    Scanner userI = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userAns = scan.NextLine(); 



    System.out.println(questionOne);    

    if(userAns == questionOneAns) {
        System.out.println("Correct!"); 
    } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong answer!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `}`  on the last line of your code =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isnt it because your scanner is called `userI` instead of `scan`?

Line 19 should be:

```
String userAns = userI.nextLine();
```

Comment: That has solved that issue but now I get -

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at javaQuiz.main(javaQuiz.java:5)